# Safari Autofill not in correct position

Tags: email, safari, position, field, autofill

I have completed a simple view in Rails for login on my website but when I load the page on Safari it automatically displays the Autofil box not under the email field but at the top left corner of the browser window, even overlapping Safari's menu bar.

Here is my login view using Boostrap :

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
    <%= form_with(url: login_path, scope: :session, local: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit 'Log in', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <% end %>
      <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When clicking in the email field, it still displays in the corner.

But when clicking on the Autofill button in the email field the Autofill box then appears at its right place, right under the field.

I'm just using bootstrap for styling, no other features here. But jQuery is imported in the project.

I found an old post for what appears to be the same issue, but no answers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue for a long time.
I'm unsure why, but changing the input id fixed it.
Mine was defaulted to id='username'.
Changing it to anything else fixed it.

Comment: I'm also having this problem but the above does not solve, the problem doesn't happen in localhost only when running on a production server. any fixes ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the id of the input element.
For me the autofill popup was displayed on top of the screen when the id was set to `email`, after removing the id the popup was shown at the correct position under the input element.

Setting the autocomplete field of the input element to `username`, as suggested in [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element) Apple developer article, also didn't change the location of the popup when the id was still defined.